# In R: move y label to the left of y axis using text function where x label is date type?

Tags: r

I would like to get the such plot ( https://www.dropbox.com/s/ed7f02jbjtxij6s/1.png ) , where the y label should on the left of y axis, but I can not modify the corresponding x axis, since x label is date type (not numeric such as 1, 2, 3 where I can set the like this text(x = -1, y = ...), something like this.)

Here, I just want to use the `text` or some `others functions` to achieve such function in which I can modify the wanted distance from the y axis, rather than `axis(2, ...)`

The csv file can be download at:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/87bwvhyo6i4f68u/test.csv

The code I used.

```
tmp <- read.csv("~/desktop/test.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
            strip.white = TRUE, header = FALSE)

tmp$V1 <- paste0(tmp$V1, '-01')
tmp <- within(tmp, {
V1 <- as.Date(V1)
date <- format(as.Date(tmp$V1, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m')
stuff <- V2
})


par(tcl = -.1, xpd = FALSE)
with(tmp, 
     plot(V1, log(stuff), type = 'n', ylim = c(0,6),
          col = 'royalblue1', lwd = 3, bty = 'l',
          axes = FALSE, xlab = '', ylab = ''))
abline(h = 0:6, lwd = .5)
with(tmp, points(x = V1, y = log10(stuff), type = 'l', 
                 col = 'royalblue1', lwd = 3))

par(xpd = TRUE)
axis(2, at = 0:6, cex.axis = .6,
     labels = NA, las = 2)


x <- with(tmp, seq(min(V1), max(V1), length = 12))
text(x = x, y = -.5, cex = .8, labels = format(x, '%Y-%m'), srt = 45)

# for y axis: here x = x[1] - 1 does not work, since x is not numeric class
text(x = x[1] - 1, y = 0:6, cex = .8, labels = format(10 ** (0:6), scientific = FALSE,     big.mark = ','))
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
Answer from MrFlick [ `hadj` and `line` within the `mtext` function works ]:

```
axis(2, at = 0:6, hadj = 1.5,
     labels = format(10 ** (0:6), scientific = FALSE, big.mark = ','), 
     las = 2)
mtext(side = 2, at = 0:6, , las = 2, line = 3,
      text = format(10 ** (0:6), scientific = FALSE, big.mark = ','))'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand why you don't want to use the standard axis labeling. There is a `hadj=` that allows you some control over where the labels are plotted

```
axis(2, at = 0:6,hadj=.6,
 labels =format(10 ** (0:6), scientific = FALSE, big.mark = ','), las = 2)
```

Otherwise, instead of `text()` you can use `mtext()` for margin text

```
mtext(side=2, at=0:6, , las=2,
 text = format(10 ** (0:6), scientific = FALSE, big.mark = ','))
```

Or if you really wanted, you can do `as.numeric(x)[1]` to convert the Date into something you can do numeric operations on. In that case `-1` will adjust by one day which may not be very large as your range is `range(as.numeric(x)) = c(12996,16191)`

Comment: Thank you. It works so good. I do not notice the `hadj` before and `mtext()` is right one too, which has a `line` parameter.